# "Ask Different" logged me in with a different account

Tags: support, user-accounts, users, openid

I created another user account on my computer, and visited *Ask Different*. I logged in using the same username I normally use (and I am using now), but despite I used the same ClaimID OpenID account, it shows me as [user6474](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6434/kiamlaluno).

I tried from my other Mac, using the similar user account I have on my Mac Mini, but I am still logged in as user6474.

To show that it's an account to which I have access, I am going to rename the account, and use kiamlaluno also on the new account.

**Update:** I tried logging in on *Stack Overflow* from the other computer, and it reports the following message:

> This OpenID is new to Stack Overflow:
>   ClaimID (kiamlaluno)
>
> However, it is know to 1 other sites in the Stack Exchange Network

To try logging in on *Stack Overflow*, I have used Google Chrome, instead of Safari, and I don't understand why I get that message.
I should not see that message, as I am using the same OpenID account I am using on this computer. I don't understand the reason why SE thinks it's a new account when I use it from a different computer and a different local user account.

Comment: Of course, I could not add the email address, as it's the same I am already using for my normal account.

Comment: I updated the user profile link, as it was not correct anymore, since I have set kiamlaluno as showed name. I still have to understand why using a different Mac account to log in on SE would cause any problem, but that is what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, from what I can tell they really are both using the same OpenID. This is likely a bug in Stack Exchange. If you're looking to regain access to your original account, I suggest using [email account recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) for the time being.

Comment: It doesn't work; it reports me the ClaimID account I am using, and then tells me to log in, but I am still being logged in with the wrong account. I will try deleting any cookies on the other computer, to see if it works.

Comment: @kiamlaluno If that doesn't work, there are basically two options - you can contact the SE team directly (team+apple@stackexchange.com) and see what they can do for you, or I can merge your old account into your new account.

Comment: I will try contacting them; you could merge the accounts, but I could still have the same problem when I try to log in from the other computer. I will try to copy the cookies between the accounts, if there is a way to do that on a Mac. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Kyle Cronin It seems I have resolved my issue; may you delete the account #6434?

Comment: @kiamlaluno OK, done

Comment: @Kyle Cronin Thank you.

Comment: the issue is that claimid supports two forms of their OpenID -- they are not the same from our perspective, they are different strings. You can search meta.so for more detail, etc